# How to print event level in lowercase using log4j12?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is there any possibility to print event levels to log in lower case in log4j 2? 
Like `%level{lowerCase=true}` in pattern in Log4j 2.
Can I process result string somehow, or use custom renderer?

Comment: can you please put your pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a [pattern](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) to the appropriate [appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) in the log4j.properties file.

For instance, with ConsoleAppender:

```
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%p{lowerCase=true}] %c{1} - %m%n
```

You can check the output [here](http://log4jtester.com/?p=%25d%20%5B%25p%7BlowerCase%3Dtrue%7D%5D%20%25c%7B1%7D%20-%20%25m%25n).